# Linq to sql: properties of properties that may be null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Simple LINQ query:

```
from transport in db.Transports
 select new
 {
    Current = transport.CurrentLocation,
    CurrentCarriers = transport.CurrentLocation.Carriers,
  };
```

Problem: `CurrentLocation` may be null. If it is, executing this query throws a NullReference. I tried adding a check like

```
transport.CurrentLocation == null ? null : transport.CurrentLocation.Carriers
```

but Linq to sql does not seem to be able to parse that.

Any nice solutions that do not involve sending an extra query for each transport?

Comment: Did you mean to say transport.CurrentLocation or transport.Current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally just use 'let'.

```
from x in Foo
let y = x.Bar
where y != null
select y.Baz;
```

UPDATE:

I think the ?? operator does translate to SQL.

Answer (score 3):

If the foreign key on Transports is nullable, you'll have to check that column for null before you can try and get the CurrentLocation object.

You could do something like this:

```
CurrentLocation = transport.currentLocationId != null ? transport.CurrentLocation : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do (you where using the wrong property):

transport.CurrentLocation == null ? null : transport.CurrentLocation.Carriers

**Update 1:** That is weird, I have used some pretty complex queries and didn't face that issue. I just checked one, don't think it matters, but mine had the check inverted:

transport.CurrentLocation != null ? transport.CurrentLocation.Carriers : null;

Can you post the complete query you tried that gives you the parse exception?

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo (I pasted the two parts of code from new and old versions respectively). Corrected the question.